# How can I use Git to track versions of a single file?

Tags: git

Let's say I have a single file, foo.txt, that I want to manage with Git, and I *don't* want to move it into its own directory out of (let's say) /Users/me/Documents, which also has a ton of other files I don't want to include in a repo with foo.txt.  Is this possible?

I tried creating a bare repo (so it would not be named .git):

```
git init --bare .foo.txt
```

and planned to exclude everything except foo.txt by putting something like this in the info/exclude file:

```
*
!foo.txt
```

but the problem I ran into is that I can't even do a `git status` as there seems to be no way to pass in a non-standard replacement for the .git directory.

Using a normal .git directory would not work, because it would limit me to ever versioning that one file, or force me to include any other files in the same repo, and I want to be able to version other files in that directory in their own repo.

I realize this is not the use case Git is designed for, but since it's a powerful tool that I'm already familiar with, I'd prefer to use it rather than something else, if there's a way to do that.

Comment: Can you have foo.txt be a symlink into a directory that contains a git repo and the real file?

Comment: I thought of doing just the opposite (symlinking to foo.txt from a normal repo with a .git directory) just as I was submitting the question.  I tried it, and it doesn't seem to work, but I'm guessing only because of the very unfortunate fact that I'm doing this on a Windoze box with a Git Bash shell.  (Yeah, the corporate standard blah blah blah.)  I haven't tested it on my MacBook Air yet.

Comment: @Daenyth I was about to suggest the same thing, but I tried first and noticed that Git only sees the symbolic link and not the file it is pointing to.

Comment: @SamyDindane: I think Daenyth was suggesting moving the actual foo.txt file into the repo's working directory, and using a symlink inside /Users/me/Documents.  I think that would work on a normal (non-Windows) OS.

Comment: @iconoclast: Git tracks symlinks as the symlink file itself, not the target of the link. Hardlink might work, but that information isn't preserved when cloning, iirc. Edit: Windows craps on that approach a bit.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ uses a repo for each file. It would be the same idea as what @Daenyth suggests, just adding the symlink out to where you want it on your filesystem

Comment: @iconoclast That would work on Windows also. ;) You need to use `mklink` to create symbolic links and not *.lnk* files.

Comment: @SamyDindane: I was using `ln -s original_file new_file` but it appeared to just make a copy.  Either that or `ls -hal` in a Git Bash shell doesn't actually tell you when a file is a symlink.

Comment: @jdi: when you clone a gist, you get a directory. Also, gists can contain multiple files, it's just that they are *usually* (repos/directories containing) single files.

Comment: @larsmans: I understand that. I'm just pointing out that this is a production example of how to version track single files, as it is what github does. Obviously you can put more files in there. Ultimately no matter what, you need a file inside a repo directory.

Comment: What's wrong with RCS for this use case?

Comment: @codegnome it might be the best option, but I'd rather use a tool I'm familiar with, and one that allows distributed usage.  If I could make git work, that would be ideal.

Comment: Windows 10 now supports symbolic links if "developer mode" is turned on (https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/#O5jxJQGLXCyewP8m.97)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do exactly what you want if you first initialize a git repository for the file:

```
git init --bare .foo.txt
```

and then run git like this:

```
git --git-dir=.foo.txt --work-tree=. status
```

Alias the first part of that second command to `git-foo` and you're off to the races.

Comment: rather than `git-foo`, I'll create a general-purpose function which will work just as well with `foo.txt` as with `bar.csv` and `baz.yaml`

Comment: `function version() { prefix='.'; filename="$1"; shift; git --git-dir="${prefix}${filename}" --work-tree=. "$@"; }`

Comment: Then you can do `version foo.txt add .` (and `.` means just `foo.txt` because you edited `.foo.txt/info/exclude` already) and `version foo.txt status` and pretty much any Git command you want.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It just prints the brief help manual "usage: git [..."

Comment: @aderchox You probably didn't initialize a repository first. My original answer assumed that if you're doing something special like this you'd know how to do it, but just to make things explicit I've edited the answer to include the initialization step. Have fun! =)

Answer (score 5):

How about using a .gitignore file to create a filter of the files that should be edited. This solution avoids hardlinks which are unsupported on windows.

For example the following file:

```
$ cat .gitignore
*
!data.xml
```

Configures git to ignore all files except "data.xml".

Comment: yes, but where do you put the .gitignore file?  If you put it in the directory with the file, then you prevent yourself from tracking any of the other files in that directory.

Comment: @iconoclast The ignore file is committed into the GIT repository. You wanted a mechanism to revision control one file. This approach means the .gitignore file lists those file(s) eligible for revision control. One repository one file... Well that's not how GIT works and I'm not sure why you'd want to do it this way. Perhaps use an older revision control system like RCS instead? :-)

Comment: It's not the normal use case for Git, but as shown by the newly accepted answer, it *is* possible.  And, as I said in the question, I'm aware it's not the normal use case, but I'd rather use Git *if* it is possible.  I'd rather use tools I know, rather than learn RCS (even if it is very simple).  This way I have the full power of Git available if I need it.  I can understand why you might prefer RCS, but there's no point in arguing over which approach is better, since that's not the point of this site, or of this question.

Comment: I use it to version the system-wide `gitconfig` in `/etc`, a simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet is to make a repo in a separate directory, and create a hardlink inside of it for each file you want to include:

```
mkdir some_repo
cd some_repo
git init
ln path/to/file file
# add & commit
```

Comment: I can't see any reason this wouldn't normally work (on a Unix-based OS).  Unfortunately hard links in Git Bash shell running on Windows don't really work.  I think the only solution for Windows is to repeatedly copy the original file into the directory and then commit it.

Comment: this is great idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's most convenient for me to track a single file in the repository stored in a separate directory.

Make a directory to store the git repository

```
mkdir my-repo-path
```

Go to worktree directory (where your desired file is located)

```
cd my-worktree-path
```

Init a separate repository inside the hidden subdirectory `.git` of `my-repo-path`

```
git init --separate-git-dir my-repo-path\.git
```

Along with the separate repository, git has created a hidden file `.git` in the worktree directory. You can delete it if you like (it may be useful if you are going to track some other file(s) in your worktree directory separately in some separate repository(ies)).

```
del /AH .git
```

In any text editor open the file `my-repo-path\.git\info\exclude` and add to the end the following lines (where `foo.txt` is the file you'd like to track):

```
*
!foo.txt
```

In the command prompt go to the git repo and add what will be committed.

```
cd my-repo-path\.git
git add .
git commit
```

Add a remote origin and push master branch, adding upstream (tracking) reference to it.

```
git remote add origin <url>
git push -u origin master
```

After that you will add the following commits from your git repo directory (see the second to last step).